# RDLC / SSRS report using external image with "#" in filename

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have a external image in a .rdlc report where I am trying to display an image that has a "#" in the the file path.  I have specified an external image, and in the file path I have: file:///C:\Users\Me#Pictures\MyPicture.jpg.

If I remove the "#" from the folder and update my path, the picture displays just fine.  With the "#" in the file path it will not display at all.

Is there an escape character that I need?  I didn't see any for XML that apply to the "#", but I did try the HTML one (`&#35;`) just in case.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer.  You have to use percent-encoding in order for this to work.  So in my case, I just replace a "#" with "%23" and all is well!